# Change route of mapped gRPC service while adding endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, .net-5

Is there a way to change the route mapping of a gRPC service in .Net5?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  // ... other stuff ...
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
  });
}
```

which gives a route something like

```
HOST/Greeter.GreeterService/SayHello
```

Now I would need to change the route to something like

```
HOST/MyCustomGreeter/SayHello
```

I have found `WithMetadata` and `WithDisplayName` but both seem have no effect

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  // ... other stuff ...
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>()
      .WithDisplayName("MyCustomGreeter")                    
      .WithMetadata(new EndpointNameMetadata("MyCustomGreeter"), new RouteNameMetadata("MyCustomGreeter"))
      ;
  });
}
```

Comment: If .NET 6 is an option, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/34062 might shed some light on this problem.

Comment: @c_thane: but this means DisplayName is actually intended to do that?

Comment: an interesting related link on Github: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/pull/153

Comment: an interesting related link on Github: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/110

Comment: an interesting related link on Github: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/14900